# Tableviewcontroller "cellForRowAtIndexPath" - index starts from 4, not 0

Tags: ios, swift

I put three table view controllers on pageviewcontroller.

The pageviewcontroller loads middle vc.

When I go to the left vc, and pull table in order to reload - I have problem that on function cellForRowAtIndexPath the indexPath.row starts from 4, not 0.

Why does the indexPath.row start from 4 and not 0?

I think, it is not about code issue! I have error:

> Cannot index empty buffer

I ve found the error. I dont know why does this happens but when I reload table (pulling it), for some reason, it takes the last row (in my case I have 4 rows on screen counting from 0) and uses it in cellAtIndex array. Every time before pulling data from internet I remove all elements from array. I changed that code, i did remove all elements before reloading and the error didnt appear. What's interesting I am using the same function on other vc and everything works.

I am making two request to download data:

```
class func JSONRequest2(urlInput: String, tableName: UITableView, action: (NSArray)->Void, refresh:UIRefreshControl, viewContr: UIViewController, hideLoadingViewAndStopAnimating: ()->Void) {



    let urlPath = urlInput

    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    println("started first json request")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            println(error)
            let stringError = error.localizedDescription
            CommonFunctions.showAlert("Ошибка", alertText: stringError, alertButtonText: "Закрыть", viewController: viewContr)
        }
        else{

            var err: NSError?
            if data != nil {

                if let jsonResult =  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSArray {
                    println("the number of news in json :\(jsonResult.count)")

                    if (err == nil) {

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            action(jsonResult)
                    //tableName.reloadData()
                        })
                    }else{
                        let stringError = err?.localizedDescription
                        CommonFunctions.showAlert("Ошибка", alertText: stringError!, alertButtonText: "Закрыть", viewController: viewContr)
                    }
                }else {
                    hideLoadingViewAndStopAnimating()
                    println("json is not valid")
                    var dic = dictForErrors()
                    CommonFunctions.showAlert("Ошибка", alertText: dic.alertText, alertButtonText: "Закрыть", viewController: viewContr)
                }
            }else {

                CommonFunctions.showAlert("Ошибка", alertText: "data is nil",alertButtonText: "Закрыть", viewController: viewContr)
                println("json data is nil")
            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}

class func JSONRequest(urlInput: String, tableName: UITableView, action: (NSArray)->Void, refresh:UIRefreshControl, category: Int, viewContr: UIViewController, hideLoadingViewAndStopAnimating: ()->Void) {

    //refresh.beginRefreshing()

    let urlPath = urlInput

    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    println("started second request")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            println(error)
            let stringError = error.localizedDescription
            CommonFunctions.showAlert("Ошибка", alertText: stringError, alertButtonText: "Закрыть", viewController: viewContr)
        }
        else{

            var err: NSError?
            if data != nil{
                if let jsonResult =  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSArray {
            println("the number of news in json :\(jsonResult.count)")

                    if (err == nil) {



                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            action(jsonResult)
                            hideLoadingViewAndStopAnimating()
                            tableName.reloadData()
                            refresh.endRefreshing()
                        })

                    }else{
                        let stringError = err?.localizedDescription
                        hideLoadingViewAndStopAnimating()
                        CommonFunctions.showAlert("Ошибка", alertText: stringError!, alertButtonText: "Закрыть", viewController: viewContr)
                    }
                }else {
                    hideLoadingViewAndStopAnimating()
                    println("json is not valid")
                    var dic = dictForErrors()
                    CommonFunctions.showAlert("Ошибка", alertText: dic.alertText, alertButtonText: "Закрыть", viewController: viewContr)
                }
            }else{

                CommonFunctions.showAlert("Ошибка", alertText: "data is nil",alertButtonText: "Закрыть", viewController: viewContr)
                println("json data is nil")
            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

This is how I am making request in order to download two request

```
self.refreshControl = self.refreshController
    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: "loadDataNewsLenta", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)


    if arrayMainPage.count > 0 {
        activityView.alpha = 0.0
        arrayNewSLenta = arrayMainPage
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }else{
        // loading first time news
        activityView.alpha = 0.5
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        isFirstReq = true
        arrayNewSLenta.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        CommonFunctions.JSONRequest2(urlString, tableName: tableView, action: desirializeJSONToArray, refresh: self.refreshController, viewContr: self, hidLoadingViewAndStopAnimating)
    }
```

I put the code above on viewdidload. This code is where I am reloading :

```
func hidLoadingViewAndStopAnimating() {
    activityView.alpha = 0
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}

func configureTableView() {
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 110.0
}

func loadDataNewsLenta() {
    arrayNewSLenta.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    isFirstReq = true
    refreshController.beginRefreshing()
    CommonFunctions.JSONRequest2(urlString, tableName: tableView, action: desirializeJSONToArray, refresh: self.refreshController, viewContr: self, hidLoadingViewAndStopAnimating)
}
```

This is all about tableview code and desirialization of json to array:

```
 // MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    println("it is news lenta count \(arrayNewSLenta.count)")
    return arrayNewSLenta.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("lentaCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as LentaTableViewCell
    let inex = indexPath.row
    cell.labelDateOfPublication.text = arrayNewSLenta[indexPath.row].pubDate
    cell.labeltitle.text = arrayNewSLenta[indexPath.row].pageTitle

    return cell
}

func desirializeJSONToArray(jsonArray: NSArray){

    for singleJSON in jsonArray{
        var singleArticle = ArticleInfo()

        if let arrayText = singleJSON as? NSDictionary{

            if let articleID = arrayText["id"] as? NSString{
                singleArticle.articleID = articleID
            }

            if let pageTitle = arrayText["pagetitle"] as? NSString {
                singleArticle.pageTitle = pageTitle
            }

            if let longTitle = arrayText["longtitle"] as? String{
                singleArticle.longTitle = longTitle
            }
            if let introText = arrayText["introtext"] as? String{

                singleArticle.introText = introText
            }
            if let contentText = arrayText["content_text"] as? String{
                singleArticle.contentText = contentText

            }
            if let category = arrayText["category"] as? String{

                singleArticle.category = category
            }
            if let imageLink = arrayText["thumbnail"] as? String{
                singleArticle.linkToImage = imageLink

            }
            if let videoLink = arrayText["video"] as? String{
                singleArticle.videoLink = videoLink
                println("hre is video link")
                println(videoLink)
            }
            if let sity = arrayText["sity"] as? String{

                singleArticle.sity = sity
            }
            if let visible = arrayText["visible"] as? String{
                singleArticle.visible = visible

            }
            if let visits = arrayText["visits"] as? String{

                singleArticle.visits = visits
            }
            if let pubDate = arrayText["pubdate"] as? String{

                singleArticle.pubDate = pubDate
            }

            // insert result into array
            arrayNewSLenta.append(singleArticle)
        }
    }
    //cycle ended
    if isFirstReq == true {

        let urlStringSecondRequest = "http://www.kfdz/artifdcles/JsonMainList"
        CommonFunctions.JSONRequest(urlStringSecondRequest, tableName: tableView, action: desirializeJSONToArray, refresh: self.refreshController, category: 0, viewContr: self, hidLoadingViewAndStopAnimating)
    }
    isFirstReq = false
}
```

The interesting fact I noticed , when I go to first vc and pull table immediately, for some reason it load cellAtIndex function using only the last row on screen(in my case index 4). on the other hand, when I go to first vc and choose some item (to see detailed view) and go back and pull table everything works. 
On more issue to say, when I change transition style of uipageviewcontroller to PageCurl I dont have this problem!

Comment: Is your `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` code updated and [tableview reloadData] called when your data changes?

Comment: This sounds as if you f***** up the cell reuse mechanism. But without could that is just a guess. I vote to close due to missing code.

Comment: Ok , i will add code

Comment: Now , After changing the transition style to page curl . I run the code, everything works good. Next step I put transition style back to scroll and now I dont have this problem anymore! Weird!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead of using 3 table view in a single view, you should use the container view in the first view and put all the view tables in different views as shown in the picture below :

[image]

You need 1 file for each table view created.

the bug can probably disappear like that

Comment: Will I have the same type of animation line in UIPAgeviewcontroller?

Comment: is segues that connect container and tableViewControllers? if yes , is it push segue?

Comment: I use 3 containers, 2/3 are hiden. The segue is the basic segue wich xcode put automatically.

Comment: I need the transition with animation! Is that possible to do? Or you are proposing to switch the visibility of containers?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible for the animations, I've not again search it. I work with the visibility of containers.

Comment: Ok, the last question, is it possible to put tableViewController instead of viewController into CONTAINER? Or container is created only for viewcontroller?

Comment: Yes, you can put all viewController types into container